# How to set up a Rest client call of a put method of a spring.boot implemented rest interface?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, rest-client

My controller:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/technology")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

private final MyService myService;

@PutMapping("/enable/{technology}")
public void useTechnology(@PathVariable String technology, Principal principal) {
    myService.[...]
}
```

My username/password in application.yaml:

```
  security:
    user:
      name: user1
      password: password
```

My RestClient call:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/technology/enable/tech1
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQx
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I always get the 401 Error though:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/technology/enable/tech1

HTTP/1.1 401 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DFE4D6D27992A0183BE7A79B551B1EE7; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 07:14:23 GMT

<Response body is empty>

Response code: 401; Time: 17ms; Content length: 0 bytes
```

What do I have to set/change to make the call work?

Comment: Can you share your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation

Comment: There's none so far.

Comment: how are you validating the token coming in request. You must have implemented some filter

Comment: sorry I am still a bloody newbie. I started the project with get methods on the root and because I added the security dependencies in maven I had the form login out of the box, with the generated password and it "just worked".